# Use AOSP generated boot.img with Android 10 factory images

Tags: boot, kernel

Is there a way to use a boot.img generated by AOSP sources with factory images of lets say sailfish (Google Pixel)?

I used to do this in the past, but now this results into a bootloop. `logcat` haven't even started at that point, so I can't find where the issue hit.

I've also compiled the kernel from sources, then packed it into the boot.img from a factory image, but still no luck.

The reason I want this:

This will allow me to have the stock applications with an insecure kernel which will enable things like `adb root`, mounting /system/ etc.
And I don't care if apps like Google Pay won't work.

Comment: boot.img contains the kernel and the kernel contains the drivers. Hence you need a matching kernel with all drivers matching for your device. An generic AOSP kernel will most likely not contain the necessary drivers.

Comment: I build a kernel for a target device. Which works well when flashing all generated imgs from AOSP. But this excludes google apps!

Comment: If boot.img works when flashed with all generated images but doesn't work alone with existing images, there's definitely an incompatibility between the boot.img and already flashed images (particularly system, vendor, odm). Troubleshooting isn't possible without logs as there can be a score of reasons for bootloop. Incompatibility can be in boot.img or in kernel configuration. Better use `pstore` or `last_kmsg` to get kernel panic logs in custom recovery from last boot. And that too will be helpful only if bootloader is able to extract boot.img properly and execute kernel binary successfully.

Comment: Maybe non matching bootloader and/or baseband versions? e.g., see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232172/how-can-i-find-the-exact-factory-image-version-that-my-pixel-is-using